# "Repeats modules with scoped bindings or declarations .. with scopes: @javax.inject.Singleton" Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm trying out the Hilt DI in my test project. I've the following module that's installed in SingletonComponent which in terms of Android is applicationComponent. However when I try to scope the provide method with @Singleton, I get the following error.

```
MyApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC repeats modules with scoped bindings or declarations:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
    - com.test.catalogue.presentation.application.MyApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC also includes:
      - com.test.catalogue.di.modules.RetrofitModule with scopes: @javax.inject.Singleton
```

Following is my module declaration.

**RetrofitModule:**

```
@Module(includes = {OKHttpModule.class})
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class RetrofitModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public MyApi providesAPI(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Retrofit providesRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory, LiveDataAdapterFactory liveDataAdapterFactory) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(liveDataAdapterFactory)
                .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    public GsonConverterFactory providesGsonConverterFactory() {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create();
    }

    @Provides
    public LiveDataAdapterFactory providesCallToLiveDataAdapterFactory() {
        return new LiveDataAdapterFactory();
    }
}
```

Build.gradle:

```
ext.hilt_version = '2.31.2-alpha'

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

OkHttpModule also has @InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class) but doesn't have @Singleton scoped provides() yet since I couldn't add them because I get the same error as mentioned above.

**How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something?**

Comment: Can you post OkHttpModule class?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem? I am using old Dagger Android in a project and get the same error after updating the library.

Comment: Same, did you ever find a solution to this?